# Creating virtual keyboard as a AngularJs module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, keyboard, angularjs-module

I have a AngularJs app and I need to create a virtual keyboard. The keyboard should be a separate module. My problem is that I am not sure how to properly structure my module? Should it be implemented as a directive, or service or etc?
I want my virtual keyboard to show whenever a textarea is clicked and hide otherwise. So I need help how to begin structuring this module. Where should the logic be implemented? Where the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting!
I would do something like that:

```
<div ng-view></div>
<div ng-controller="virtualKeyboardController()">
  <virtual-keyboard></virtual-keyboard>
</div>
```

The `<virtual-keyboard>` directive will replace the element with the right HTML (you could also use a `ng-include` instead of a directive; I personally believe the directive is the better way here).
Then the `virtualKeyboardController` will use a custom service that gives you some methods to:

- show the keyboard;
- hide the keyboard;
- do other keyboard stuff.

The service must then be injected inside every controller that could use a virtual keyboard and bind all the `textarea`s to it (that's probably the annoying part, if your app is already done).

**NOTE:** I created a `<div>` which contains the `<virtual-keyboard>` only as an example, to avoid controllers' conflicts, but there may be a better solution; also adding a `ng-if` to the parent `<div>` you could do the show/hide check out of the directive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to make Chrome Virtual Keyboard into Angularjs and it is difficult to organize the files.https://github.com/xontab/Chrome-Virtual-Keyboard